# Different default color for each font in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, math-mode, color, context

Is there a way to specify the color along with the font name when using `simplefonts`? At the moment, I use the following to setup my default fonts.

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\setmainfont[Ubuntu]
\setsansfont[charter] % the reversal of serif and sans roles was intentional
\setmonofont[FreeMono]
\setmathfont[euler]
```

This is working as expected. However, I'd like to have all math to be shown in dark red. I can switch it manually every time like so:

```
\color[darkred]{$my+new+equation$}
```

1. Is there something I can add to `\setmathfont` so that it changes the color without having to type the extra color commands every time? Ideally, it should work for all the commands used for display-math and inline-math.
2. In addition to that, when the surrounding text overrides the color, the color should be in the new, overriding color instead. So, `\color[green]{Important: you need to tune $x$ to use the above.}`, should be set entirely in green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for the first of your two points is to use `\appendtoks` like in this example:

```
% For inline math
% \appendtoks\green\to\everymath

% For display math
% \appendtoks\green\to\everydisplay

% For inline and display math
\appendtoks\green\to\everymathematics

\starttext

\math{a^2+b^2=c^2}

\startformula
    a^2+b^2=c^2
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

The green colour switch is applied to inline and display math.

*Edit*: Changes applied to `\everydisplay` or `\everymathematics` affect text included in the display math as well. I'm not sure if there's a clean solution for this, but you can inject code directly before the `\text` is printed. Here I print the text inside the display math in blue:

```
\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\mathtext
  {\mathortext\blue\math_text_choice\hbox}
\protect
```

Example:

```
\appendtoks\green\to\everymathematics

\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\mathtext
  {\mathortext\blue\math_text_choice\hbox}
\protect

\starttext

\math{a^2+b^2=c^2}

\startformula
    a^2+b^2=c^2
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

The result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! I am using this for now, but it colors even the `\text{}` sections within formulas, which I prefer it avoid. Though a font-based solution would work better for me, I like this is a good default for the time being.

Comment: @prash Thanks for the obervation, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's been very useful!